# Why is Harry unable to crucio Bellatrix after she killed Sirius, but could crucio a Death Eater when he spat at McGonagall

Tags: harry-potter, spells

I've always hated that Harry couldn't crucio Bellatrix after she killed Sirius, but could crucio a Death Eater after he spat at McGonagall. Is spitting at a teacher worse than some lady who just *murdered* your godfather and *tortured your friend's parents into insanity?!* Why couldn't Harry crucio Bellatrix after she killed Sirius, but could crucio a Death Eater when he spat at McGonagall?

Comment: Two thoughts: Trauma affects people in the moment in different ways. And J. Random Death eater is prolly less scary/intimidating/emotionally jarring than Belatrix Lestrange.

Comment: it is pure guess and doesn't deserve an answer, but the fact is Harry knew Sirus for basically a few month. McGonagal was basically Harry second mom (first one being Ms Wesley) for 6 years (Maybe even without Harry himself realizing it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Bellatrix told Harry, "You have to mean it".

I suspect it's just a matter of what "you have to mean it" really means. Harry was certainly *angrier*, but he didn't know how to use that anger to focus the spell. He was just going through the motions, as it were, with Bellatrix. Later, he knew how to cast the spell "properly", even if he has a less personal connection with the target.